# Node Editor is blank and Inactive, also in new instances

Tags: node-editor

I have probably activated some setting in blender 2.8 that has turned nodes inactive and all options in node editor inactive. They worked fine before but not anymore.
'Use Nodes' is active and issue exists even when adding new materials.
Issue also exists when opening new file.
Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "inactive"? Do you mean that you can see nodes in your object materials, but they are all greyed-out and you can't interact with them or that you simply can't add any node and there's no material output node?

Comment: Hello :). You can share your [.blend file here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so others can take a look.